# C#.net inheritance between more than 2 classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If i have the classes `A`, `B` ,`C`

```
class B : A (inherited from Class A )
class C : B (inherited from Class B )
```

so by default , class `C` will inherit from class `A`

how to prevent it

Comment: Umm... How do you prevent your grandparent from being your grandparent? You can't. Why do you want to? What is the *real* problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: If it ever comes to that......know you have a wrong structure.....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent inheriting certain aspects of a class when you inherit from it. You will need to create class `C` all on its own.